# Difference between 'php artisan serve' and 'php -S localhost:8000 -t public'?

Tags: php, laravel, windows-7, xampp

I want to run my laravel5 project with

```
php artisan serve
```

but i got an empty page. Then I tried with

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

and it worked.

The strange thing is, the first command worked for me at the beginning and now it doesnt.

I also tried to call in my browser:

```
http://localhost/myProject/public/
```

In this case, its worked but without loading my css files.

**Can someone explain me what the difference is between these commands and why the first one not working for me anymore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to understand Laravel Coding is read the Code itself.

You can refer to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php`

And the command actually call to this.

`/**
     * Get the full server command.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function serverCommand()
    {
        return sprintf('%s -S %s:%s %s/server.php',
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false)),
            $this->host(),
            $this->port(),
            ProcessUtils::escapeArgument($this->laravel->basePath())
        );
    }`

What you asking what is the different. The different is `php artisan serve` specific add the `/server.php` in the argument and `php -S` does not include that.